# Overflowing in state array using Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, frontend, state, redux-toolkit

I got a situation where i add a box from an inputs and dispatched it when the user click save. But, the problem is when i add another box its values gets added to the old/existing array. So, for my Reducers as shown is there anything should be added or changed in order to achieve that every box should have its own skills.

```
    import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  roles: [],
  role: "",
  description: "",
  requiredSkill: [],
  complimentarySkill: [],
  requiredSkills: "",
  complimentarySkills: "",
};

const rolesSlice = createSlice({
  name: "teamRoles",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addRole: (state, action) => {
      if (!state.roles.includes(action.payload)) {
        state.roles = [...new Set([...state.roles, action.payload])];
      }
    },
    setRole: (state, action) => {
      state.role = action.payload;
    },
    setDescription: (state, action) => {
      state.description = action.payload;
    },
    addRequiredSkill: (state, action) => {
      if (!state.requiredSkill.includes(action.payload)) {
        state.requiredSkill = [
          ...new Set([...state.requiredSkill, { ...action.payload }]),
        ];
      }
    },
    setRequiredSkill: (state, action) => {
      state.requiredSkills = action.payload;
    },
    addComplimentarySkill: (state, action) => {
      if (!state.complimentarySkill.includes(action.payload)) {
        state.complimentarySkill = [
          ...new Set([...state.complimentarySkill, action.payload]),
        ];
      }
    },
    setComplimentarySkill: (state, action) => {
      state.complimentarySkills = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const {
  addRole,
  setRole,
  setDescription,
  addRequiredSkill,
  setRequiredSkill,
  addComplimentarySkill,
  setComplimentarySkill,
} = rolesSlice.actions;

export default rolesSlice.reducer;
```

and for the code for the component when dispatched as shown here

```
   {userRequiredSkills.length > 0
              ? userRequiredSkills.map((skill) => (
                  <div className="role__text-cont">
                    <p
                      key={skill.roleRequiredSkills}
                      className="role__text"
                    >
                      {skill.roleRequiredSkills}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                ))
              : null}
```

what is being rendered on the page is as follows when one box is added and then when i add another box

[image: When One box is added]
[image: Additional box is added]
[image: Redux tools of the added states]